# How to set text colour in android apps

Tags: android-layout

I am a complete newbee to android and Java programming, although I have done quite a lot with c and c++. I am working my way through some tutorials at present. I hope you will bear with me if I ask what may be a simple question to most. I have been trying to find out how to set a font colour in android apps (I am using eclipse IDE), in the same way that the background colour can be set using android:background="#88FFFF00" for instance.

Answer (score 1):

In the xml just put:

```
android:textColor="#88FFFF00"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I looked around google and other sites and could not find any simple way to do this, they all seemed extremely complicated. Anyway thanks again, your advice is extremely welcome.

Comment: and from code you can do the following `txtView.setTextColor(R.color.White);`